# Ubuntu Software App (Software Center)

Tags: software-center

Software Center only shows "Featured Application" and "Editors Pick" and nothing else when "All" is selected. Has anyone else seen this? If so what is to be done? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu software not showing any software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760817/ubuntu-software-not-showing-any-software)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Ubuntu Software Center dropping previously provided applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051107/why-is-ubuntu-software-center-dropping-previously-provided-applications)